# How to use poweRlaw package in R for very big datasets?

Tags: r, power-law, bigdata

I am fitting a power law to a 45 million rows vector, for which I am using the poweRlaw package in R: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.3492.pdf

The most computationally intensive part of the process is estimating the lower bound, which is done with the `estimate_xmin()` function. It's taking a lot of time.

The code goes like this (`w` is the vector and `c_pl` comes from "continuous power-law"):

```
c_pl <- conpl$new(w)
est <- estimate_xmin(c_pl)
c_pl$setXmin(est)
```

I am wondering how to use the `estimate_xmin()` function in a way that minimises processing time (maybe parallel computations?) I am working on an AWS instance with 16 cores and 64GB of RAM. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `estimate_xmin` takes so long is because it is trying all possible values of `xmin`. The function has an argument `xmins` that you can use to truncate this search, e.g.

```
estimate_xmin(m, xmins=c(10, 100, 1000, 10000))
```

will find the optimal xmin out of 10, 100, 1000 and 10000.

Comment: Thanks! This works. Actually, Colin, your package has been very useful for me. Thanks for writing poweRlaw.